# Nested CSS Columns not rendering properly - Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I am having below issue only on **Mozilla Firefox Ver. 59.0.2(64 bit)**.

Am trying to render content using nested CSS Columns with column-rule to get line between columns. But lines are extended above and below content, check below image for reference.

[image]

Here is the snippet am using, and fidler [here](https://jsfiddle.net/d8838opa/9/). **Please check on mozilla firefox.**

```css
.header,
.footer {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.img-100 {
  width: 100%;
}

.column-2 {
  columns: 2;
  -webkit-columns: 2;
  -moz-columns: 2;
  column-rule: 1px solid red;
  -webkit-column-rule: 1px solid red;
  -moz-column-rule: 1px solid red;
}

.column-3 {
  columns: 3;
  -webkit-columns: 3;
  -moz-columns: 3;
  column-rule: 1px solid #000;
  -webkit-column-rule: 1px solid #000;
  -moz-column-rule: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">

</div>
<div class="column-2">
  <img src="https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/4643298-images.jpg" class="img-100">
  <div class="column-3">
    The Jodhpur High Court will tomorrow hear a plea by the Rajasthan Police to pronounce the judgement in a rape case against self-styled godman Asaram Bapu in a jail court to avoid any law and order situation in the city. The judgement in the case is scheduled
    for April 25. Police commissioner Ashok Rathore said the forces have requested the judiciary not to pronounce the judgement in the case from the court as it may lead to clashes between the security forces and the godman's followers in the court premises.
    He also refuted reports that the police had urged the court to shift the pronouncement date in the case from April 25 to April 17. "We have moved an application requesting the pronouncement of judgement in the case in the jail's court in view of the
    threat to law and order situation in the city," Additional Advocate General S K Vyas said. In its application, the police have stated that there would be a huge presence of Asaram's followers in the city on the judgment day, and that the followers
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">

</div>
```

Comment: it seems a bug, try to add/remove the property using the console and you will see that it behave differently from time to time

Comment: a quick fix is to add `overflow:hidden;` to column-2

Comment: @TemaniAfif yes, it looks like a bug and behaving differently in different versions. Anyhow `overflow:hidden` gives fix for now. Thanks..:)